# export Environment_Variable = something --> = [equals sign] not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, environment-variables, conda

I'm still quite new to Ubuntu.

I've been installing tensorflow (with CUDA) for some university project; we are to work in conda. After activating my tensorflow conda environment, my instructions tell me to set the path (which is, as far as I understand an environment variable?) for pip installation:

> Next, set the path to the binary file for the pip installation, by typing the following command:
>
> ```
> ( t e n s o rfl o w ) $ export TF BINARY URL = \
> h t t p s : / / s t o r a g e . g o o g l e a p i s . com/ t e n s o rf l o w / li n u x /\
> cpu/ t e n s o rfl o w −0.11.0 rc1−cp35−cp35m−li n u x x 8 6 6 4 . whl
> ```
>
> To finalize the installation type:
>
> ```
> ( t e n s o rfl o w ) $ pip3 i n s t a l l −−ig no r e−i n s t a l l e d \
> −−upgrade $TF BINARY URL
> ```
>
> You can now proceed with Test run TensorFlow.

(All the spaces just come from the latex-pdf, of course I left them out.)

So I typed:

```
export TF_BINARY_URL = https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Problem is, command line tells me that:

```
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl': not a valid identifier
```

I just can't find what I've been doing wrong, and now I wonder whether there is some error in the instructions or whether I might have made some really stupid mistake? From what I have read it might be that the usage of `export` here is wrong, but I'm totally new to Ubuntu and bash shell and what I read there was ambiguous.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to remove any excessive spaces in your post? Namely, in the commands. In their current state, it's very hard to read/understand what's going on and (as such) how to fix it. We need the exact command you ran.

Comment: "of course I left them out." ... doesn't look like you did. Post the exact command you ran, please.

Comment: Sorry, just went to sleep frustrated. I left in the original instructions, but also editet in the very query i used. Stupid me, should have done that straight away. Thank you!

Comment: No spaces should be around the `=`.

Comment: Cant upvote a comment sadly but thank you kindly!